# While loop in external class java

Tags: java, while-loop, redirect

Well, things should work, but as always they don't :D. Perhaps I omitted some sort of issue that is obvious to more seasoned programmers.

In main I do stuff like this

```
    ACProcess ACProcess = new ACProcess();
    new ACFrame(ACProcess);
```

`ACFrame` is just a `JFrame` containing all the `JPanels`.
`ACProcess` will be responsible for connecting through usb, using jd2xx library to access controller. I absolutely need to have a `while(true)` loop there (because of question-answer type of communication with access controller) and just "redirect" it with methods, currently I am testing if it works, and it doesn't. My `ACProcess()` constructor has a loop like this:

```
    while(true) {
        if(verify) {
            System.out.println(test);
            test++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("works");
        }
    }
```

and methods to direct it, like these:

```
    public void test() {
        verify=false;
    }

    public void test2() {
        verify=true;
    }

    public boolean verifyValue() {
        return verify;
    }
```

What should I do to have this loop running? (My compiler doesn't show any of the `System.out.println()` so I guess it doesn't work.

Comment: Your compiler won't run the program, it will only generate the bytecode. Are you sure you are executing the program? (Eclipse: Run -> Run As -> Java Application)

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with your `while` loop; it's more likely that execution never gets there: try putting a print statement right before the while loop.

Comment: I'm using netbeans and I'm pretty sure it runs :D, I see my frame and panels and buttons work alright. print statement in constructor b4 loop gave nothing. I do have however "new instance ignored" warning at new ACFrame, it shows neverhteless :/.

Comment: Post the correct code, as it exists in your java file.  We only need to see the constructor which as you claim is where this while loop is.

Comment: Note that if you do manage to get into the while loop, and don't spawn a thread for it, your constructor will never return.

Comment: I think what Thomas wrote is the issue here, I'll check out those threads :D. We'll see if it works

Comment: Actually that was a warning about what happens next.  If that were the immediate problem, it would never get to the ACFrame line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas guided me, it was as I predicted, something more seasoned programmers knew and I didn't. After adding Thread as in this example
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

All works fine. Thanks for help guys.